# Generate to root dir from nuxt.config.js

Tags: node.js, npm, nuxt.js

I'm using NodeJS and NuxtJS and I need to publish directly to the root (*example.com*) folder instead of */dist*.
My config files path and the `.sh` with `npm run generate` are in the folder *example.com/blogfiles/*.

I tried setting *dir* from `dir: '/blog'/'` in *nuxt.config.js* to:

```
{
  dir: '/'
}
```

This results an error:

> Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rmdir '/'

How to enable publishing to root?

Comment: You could probably use a node.js script after the `generate` to move the content of `dist` into the root directory. I doubt this is a good idea to force on this one, if it's even doable.

Comment: @Tom Have you tried the `subFolders` property? https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/dist/#the-subfolders-property

Comment: @painotpi Yes. My settings are: `generate: {
  subFolders: false
}` Should that output the files from a subfolder to root? This is not the case for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following,

Have a script that moves your files after build,

```js
// move-files.js
const mvdir = require('mvdir');

async function move() {
  await mvdir('dist', '../');
}

move();
```

And call this with your `generate` script in your package.json.

```
"generate": "nuxt generate && node move-files.js"
```

Comment: I guess that he cannot do this on the server, otherwise he would already achieved that.

Comment: @kissu okay, will wait for OP to validate that. But that should be possible even on the server, right? it's still a file-system at the end of the day.

Comment: @painotpi Thanks for you anwer. I tried you code but got this error after execution: "    [116] => Error: Cannot find module 'mvdir'" - What is the correct way to add the module mvdir?

Comment: @Tom just an `npm i mvdir` should suffice